# Gibbon::MailChimpError (the server responded with status 400 @title="Invalid Resource"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I am trying to use gibbon gem and following their github docs. Here is the code I have

```
class ChimpController < ApplicationController
  def create
    send_to_mail_chimp ( params[:email])
  end

  def send_to_mail_chimp(email)
    puts "send email is #{email}"
    gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "bla")
    gibbon.timeout = 10
    gibbon.lists('e61cf2454d').members.create(body: {email_address: email, status: "subscribed"})
  end
end
```

`<%= simple_form_for :email, url: newsletter_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
<%= f.input :email, input_html: {class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'enter email'} %>
<% end %>`

The exact error message is

```
Gibbon::MailChimpError (the server responded with status 400 @title="Invalid Resource", @detail="The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.", @body={"type"=>"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/", "title"=>"Invalid Resource", "status"=>400, "detail"=>"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.", "instance"=>"", "errors"=>[{"field"=>"email_address", "message"=>"Schema describes string, object found instead"}]}, @raw_body="{\"type\":\"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/\",\"title\":\"Invalid Resource\",\"status\":400,\"detail\":\"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.\",\"instance\":\"\",\"errors\":[{\"field\":\"email_address\",\"message\":\"Schema describes string, object found instead\"}]}", @status_code=400):
  app/controllers/chimp_controller.rb:10:in `send_to_mail_chimp'
  app/controllers/chimp_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting back is telling you exactly what the problem is:

```
{
    "field": "email_address",
    "message": "Schema describes string, object found instead"
}
```

You're passing the email in as a javascript object (ruby hash) instead of a string. All you need to pass is the raw email address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give the `members` method a MD5 hash of the lower case email address ([via the mailchimp subscriber management](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/)).  Try

```
def send_to_mail_chimp(email)
  puts "send email is #{email}"
  gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "bla")
  gibbon.timeout = 10
  md5_email = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email['email'].downcase)
  # I prefer 'upsert' to 'create' but should work with either
  gibbon.lists('e61cf2454d').members(md5_email).upsert(body: {email_address: email['email'], status: "subscribed"})
end
```

Comment: undefined method `downcase' for {"email"=>"mahesh@digifutura.com"}:ActionController::Parameters

Comment: For some reason your parameter is coming through as a hash, not a string. Should be fixed

Comment: That also could be what was causing your initial error

Comment: The md5 is something MailChimp provides, not something you have to provide.

Comment: I think you need to give the md5 if you want to use `upsert`, which is essentially `find_or_create_by`. If you want to use `create` you shouldn't have to

Comment: Thanks roco for clarifications.